# Python BeautifulSoup html tag parsing issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

New to Python and I've been looking to use BeautifulSoup to print all "Value Needed" within html similar to:

```
<!-- UNIQUE COMMENT 1 -->
</td>
<td class="same_class_name">
 Value Needed A
</td>
<!-- UNIQUE COMMENT 2 -->
</td>
<td class="same_class_name">
 Value Needed B
</td>
<!-- UNIQUE COMMENT 3 -->
</td>
<td class="same_class_name">
 Value Needed C
</td>
```

I've tried writing this snippet of code:

```
valueNeeded = soup.body.find('td', attrs={'class':'same_class_name'}).text
print valueNeeded
```

This will indeed print out "Value Needed A" but my issue is it doesn't account for the next two values. I've also tried to identify if there's a way to find the unique value in the comment first then find the value, but still no luck.

Any help to pull out the values would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
>>> valueNeeded = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'same_class_name'})
>>> for tag in valueNeeded:
...     print tag.text.strip()
... 
Value Needed A
Value Needed B
Value Needed C
```

Note, I removed the `soup.body` from your code, as it seemed to return `None` for me.

If you're using BeautifulSoup version 3, then you'll want to use `findAll()`.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I included the code, but I'm receiving the following error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. I am using BeautifulSoup version 3 if that helps.

Comment: @JohnRay How did you create `soup`?

Comment: This is how I was creating the soup: 

<code>
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

br = mechanize.Browser()
page = br.open('example.website.com')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
</code>

Comment: @JohnRay Try putting the `soup.body` back in